# Notes 9 Mailbox Crashes - dialogbox method

Tags: crash, dialog, lotus-notes, lotusscript

We have a customized mail template, and we have used ws.dialogbox method in queryclose. In notes 9 this appears to be a problem and notes is crashing exactly while executing the code of dialogbox (While editing external email only this crash is happening). In the previous version of notes this code worked without any errors. Here is the code :

```
On Error GoTo DocDeleted

If uiCurrDoc.FieldGetText("SendOrEsc") = "" And _
uiCurrDoc.EditMode  And _
((uiCurrDoc.document.DoCloseDialog(0)) Or (uiCurrDoc.document.ActionInProgress(0) = "4096")) And _
(LCase$(uiCurrDoc.FieldGetText("DeleteFlag")) <> "true") Then

On Error GoTo 0

Set tempDoc = CurrDoc.ParentDatabase.CreateDocument     
**varResponse = wsCurrDoc.DialogBox("TLSCloseMailWindow", True, True, , , , , "Close Window", tempdoc)**
```

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the Notes client (9.0.1 FP5)? If not, then try an upgrade

Comment: Can you check the NSD to see, what EXACTLY makes the client crash? Try setting `DEBUG_LS_DUMP=1` to the notes.ini of your test- client and let the NSD complete its job. Probably it is not the Dialogbox but something within the Dialog form that makes your client crash...

Comment: Thanks, a .dmp file has been generated. But could you please guide me how to identify the error.